# What is the contrapositive of an quantified statement?

Tags: real-analysis

I am instructed to formalize the contrapositive of "no natural number smaller than 70 is divisible by 71"

Suppose I formalize the statement as:

$$(\forall{x \in \mathbb{N}})(\forall{k \in \mathbb{N}})( x < 70 \implies \lnot(71k = x) )$$

I understand how to take the contrapositive of the inner "open" statement in isolation:

$$(71k = x) \implies x \ge 70 $$

However I an unclear on what happens to the quantifiers.

Do they flip as well, eg. "there exists some natural number such that it being a multiple of 71 implies that it is greater than 70":

$$(\exists{x \in \mathbb{N}})(\exists{k \in \mathbb{N}})((71k = x) \implies x \ge 70)$$

Or do they remain unchanged eg. "there is no natural number such that it being a multiple of 71 implies that it is less than 70":

$$(\forall{x \in \mathbb{N}})(\forall{k \in \mathbb{N}})(\lnot(71k = z) \implies x < 70  )$$

Comment: I suggest just "thinking" about it.  The original statement is "if a natural number is smaller than 70, then it is not divisible by 71".  The contrapositive is thus, "If a number _is_ divisible by 71, then it is _above_ , or equal to, 70".  Thus $\forall x \in \mathbb{N} : x \mod 71 = 0 \rightarrow x \geq 70$.

Comment: Arguably, you could consider $x\in\mathbb{N}$ as a part of the hypothesis, and you could say something along the lines of "then $x>70$ or $x\not\in\mathbb{N}$" but usually we would think of it as being a part of the context and not worth our time to consider what happens if negated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are negating the whole statement, then the quantifiers would flip:

! (∀x∈ℕ)(∀k∈ℕ)(x<70⟹¬(71k=x))

$\equiv$

(∃x∈ℕ)(∃k∈ℕ)(x<70$\wedge$¬¬(71k=x)) [of course the ¬¬ would cancel]

However, the contrapositive is always taken of a statement of the form $A\Rightarrow B$, without any quantifiers.

If you were looking for a statement equivalent to your statement above, then you are always allowed to replace $A\Rightarrow B$ with its contrapositive.  If you replaced it in your case, you would get:

(∀x∈ℕ)(∀k∈ℕ)(x<70⟹¬(71k=x))

$\equiv$

(∀x∈ℕ)(∀k∈ℕ)(71k=x⟹¬(x<70))

Note that in this case, no negation is involved.